# Can someone explain the syntax of this code?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query in a php file which works fine:

```
$query = "SELECT `name` FROM users WHERE name='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$name)."'";
```

I got it in a tutorial so I'm trying to wrap my head around the syntax. Specifically this part:

```
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$name)."'
```

If the function mysql_real_escape_string() returns a string, why are double quotes needed? Also, I understand in php the . means concatenation so is this code adding to the empty string""?

Please help, I'm really screwed up on this one.

Answer (score 3):

The double quotes are needed because this is using string concatenation to compose a query. This is a really messy way to do this sort of thing as the `mysqli` driver has support for placeholders:

```
$query = "SELECT `name` FROM users WHERE  name=?";
```

The `?` represents where your data will go. You then use the [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method to add your `$name` value in there.

If you're disciplined about using placeholders you won't have to worry about quoting or [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of quotes in most computer programs, `'` and `"`. You use two of the same type to enclose a string, like `'abc'` or `"def"`. However, when you need quotes inside the other quotes, you can put `'"'`. The syntax does not respond to the quote of different type. The same principle applies in here.

In this case, the line of code can be represented as

```
`$query = "SELECT `name` FROM users WHERE  name=''";`
```

but the single quotes needs content in them. That gets added by the concatenation.

Comment: Why does this not work? $query = "SELECT `name` FROM users WHERE name='mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$name)'";

Comment: @KarlNeumann sorry about that typo. There was an issue with quote enclosure.

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes identify strings in the SQL query that you are building.

Your query will result for example in:

```
 SELECT `name` FROM users WHERE name='John';
```

(note the quotes surrounding John)

The backticks are used to scape objects names.

Answer (score 0):

There is no empty strings in this code. The last `"'"` is just closing the single quoted string that was opened in `name='"`. In mysql queries, strings must be enclosed in quotes and the here the function returns string which is enclosed in single quotes. This can be clarified like this:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$name);
$query = "SELECT `name` FROM users WHERE name='".$name."'";
```

Suppose if the variable `$name = 'Joffery'`
Then the `$query` variable will be printed like this

```
SELECT `name` FROM users WHERE name='Joffery'
```